# Paste Excel range into PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Getting an error on the `PPTPres.SLides(2).Shapes.Paste`

> run time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set

```vb
Sub ExportExceldatatoPPT()

    Dim PPTApp As Powerpoint.Application
    Dim PPTPres As Powerpoint.Presentation
    Dim PPTSlide As Powerpoint.Slide
    
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    Dim RngArray As Variant
    
    Set PPTApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPTApp.Visible = True
    PPTApp.Presentations.Open Filename:="W:\Shared With Me\investments_team\investments_front_office\Fortitude Re\Asset Rotation Tracking\Asset Rotation Weekly Updates\Asset Rotation Test.pptx"`
    
    Set ExcRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1. Overview").Range("B4:T42")
    
    ExcRng.Copy
    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides(2)
    PPTPres.Slides(2).Shapes.Paste
    
End Sub
```

Comment: From `PPTPres.SLides(2).Shapes.Paste` , it looks like `SLides(2)` or `Shapes` is NULL.

Comment: You don't set `PPTPres` to anything?

Comment: ***Object variable not set** You attempted to use an object property without a valid object. If you leave out the Set statement, an error will be generated on the reference to the object. To correct this error. Specify a reference for the object variable.* From the succinct VBScript or the much longer VBA which says the same thing in many sentences. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91

Comment: Thanks, what should I set PPTPres and PPTSlide to, for it to go to Slide 2?

Comment: Slide2 is the third slide?

Comment: Slide2 is 2nd slide, so I guess it should be PPTPres.Slide(1).Shapes.Paste?

Comment: Change PPTApp.Presentations.Open Filename:{etc}  to Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Open Filename:{etc}